# Access HP Proliant DL385 BIOS

Tags: hp, hp-proliant, bios

How do I access the BIOS of a HP ProLiant DL385 server?

It doesn't have any hard drives, just power, monitor & keyboard connected. The keyboard is a PS/2 Microsoft Media keyboard with an (annoying) F-lock button.

It turns on, the HP ProLiant splash screen (with logo, no text) appears for a second, then the screen goes black. It remains on, and the splash screen doesn't appear again (no boot loop).

I've tried pressing (holding, and repeatedly pressing) F1, F8, F10, and delete during the whole process. I've had F-lock on and off, nothing makes a difference.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to press `F9` at the end of the [POST sequence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power-on_self-test). You will also hear a double-beep prior to the loading of the OS. That's another point where you can press `F9`.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the issue - the (old & crappy) monitor I was connecting it to needed to turn off/on after the splash screen to display the new image (different resolution/format?)